# Data on the number of "remote" workers by country

Tags: data-request, economics, labor

I'm trying to find estimates of how many workers in each country have remote (also known as 'virtual' or 'digital') sources of income. This is focused on developing countries so I really need data that goes beyond advanced industrial economies.

What would also be helpful is a storehouse of data from popular freelancing websites, or even case studies focused on individual countries such as the Philippines, Ukraine, others. The data will be used for an economic development study (non-commercial).